# Unable to take input beyond 4094 characters in a string

Tags: c

I was wodering that why the output is 4094 instead of 500000.

My input is 500000 long character file without any space.
For eg:(vjdnvkk......abcf),with no. of char = 500000.

Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s[500000];
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("%d",strlen(s));
}
```

Comment: I've done:

```
perl -e "print 'x'x50000" > 50k.txt
```

And used it as an input to feed the program and it printed out 50000. So I think something is wrong with your input data. Like @ForceBru mentions, it might be that you have a special character of some sort.

Comment: Perhaps your file contains null-terminators or newlines

Comment: Adding on to the comment by @ForceBru : you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22060273/4142560

Comment: Works for me using @WojciechAKoszek's input. Though there's two warnings: you forgot to include `string.h` and the `printf` format for `strlen` should be `%zu` for `size_t`.

Comment: What is the evidence that the file "input is 500000 long character file" is that length and no white-space and no null character?

Answer (score 1):

That's because 4095th byte of the input file is zero, and `strlen` counts up until it encounters the first zero.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

1. If the file truly consists of 500,000 non-white-spaces characters as claimed by OP: "My input is 500000 long character file", then code needs `s` to be 1 larger to prevent undefined behavior.  Also use a matching specifier to print the length of `s`. [@Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631643/unable-to-take-input-beyond-4094-characters-in-a-string/36633287#comment60858863_36631643)

   ```
   int main(void) {
       char s[500000 + 1];
       if (scanf("%500000s",s) == 1) {
         printf("%zd",strlen(s));
       }
   }
   ```
2. OP claims a file exists "500000 long character file", yet this code does not read from a file, but from `stdin`.  It is possible the *unposted* call of the program and its re-directed input is using some mechanism that limits the input to 4094.
3. The "500000 long character file" simple has white-space about the 4094th character.
4. As [@Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631750/2410359) answered, the 4094th character (first location of the 0th one) is a null character.  `"%s"` will surprisingly read multiple null characters as a null character is not a white-space.

Comment: Actually this code reads from stdin and and when I tried to copy the contents from file to input window then it stops after 4094 letters.WHY is it so and what are its alternatives?

Comment: @Fcudber "I tried to copy the contents from file to input window "  What is an "input window"?  Certainly that is not part of your code and may have a size limit.